# Custom tabs in bot framework c#

Tags: c#, jquery, sharepoint, botframework, microsoft-teams

I'm new to bot framework. I want to develop a custom tab in MS teams which will fetch data from `SharePoint` and show in teams tab. I don't want to use `Node.js` as I have no idea of it.

So, is there any way I can implement it using `c#` or `jQuery`.
Kindly share some references.

Comment: Yes, You can bring a  sharepoint page inside teams, You need to set the sharepoint page url with in your app manifest and need to add sharepoint domain within your app manifest. Please take a look at [Custom Tab with Sharepoint with in Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/tabs-in-sharepoint#introduction).

Comment: @Trineta-MSFT, i don't want to create a Separate SharePoint page, i have created a view in my message extension solution and want to use that only. Use case is, i want to get the channel ID/ channel name and load view based on that channel name and data in view will be populated from SharePoint list

Comment: Please take a look at [Get Context for Your Tab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/access-teams-context).

Comment: I tried the same thing but it seems when i'm deploying to azure my changes are not getting reflected in Tabs, can you suggest why this is happening.

Comment: Could you please share your app manifest so we can look into the issue further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tabs in Microsoft teams are nothing but a web page, so you can have a simple HTML page and use SharePoint REST API to fetch data and then bind it to the HTML page.
If page is not hosted in SharePoint then you can use oAuth for authentication and fetch data by passing assess token.